# Same uri http and https

Tags: http, https, cpanel

I need to create secure url for my website.

http://****.com/same.html and  https://****.com/same.html.
Both uri must apply  same file same.html.

How can I do this in cpanel.
I have already generated ssl key for domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentRoot for http and https is same in cPanel. Just install the SSL and it's done.

Dedicated IP is needed to install SSL. If your site is already on dedicated IP, Then get "crt" certificate from from your SSL provider and ask your hosting provider to install it.